# Laravel validation for Array not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have the following naming conventions for input fields.

```
course_details[0][d_Total_Score]
course_details[1][d_Total_Score]
course_details[2][d_Total_Score]
```

Now I want to validate these fields with some rules. The following is the code I tried.

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'course_details.0.d_Total_Score' => 'required',
    'course_details.1.d_Total_Score' => 'required',
    'course_details.2.d_Total_Score' => 'required'
]);
```

I have taken reference from [here](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/form-array-validation-in-laravel-5-2/)

But this doesn't seem to be working.

HTML CODE:

```
<input placeholder="SAT score " class="form-control form-control-sm valid" id="d_Score_Sub_Category_SAT" name="course_details[0][d_Total_Score]" value="" aria-invalid="false" type="text">
```

**RESOLVED**: As d3jn said, the validations should not override anywhere.

Comment: First of all, you can actually use wilcard syntax and let Laravel iterate through your `corse_details` with one rule: `'course_details.*.d_Total_Score' => 'required'`. More about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays).

Also provide code of where are you using this rules - in `FormRequest` class? Using `Validator`? Are there any exceptions? We need more info.

Comment: @d3jn, please check updates

Comment: Check `dd($request->input('course_details'))` when you send your requests. I assume "this doesn't seem to be working" means you are not getting any errors even when not specifying `d_Total_Score`. Or is it the opposite and you are always getting validation errors?

Comment: I am getting array (
    'd_Total_Score' => NULL,
  ), for example.  But it is required. And the form is getting submitted. But it should not.

Comment: Provide HTML code of your form inputs then. Your input names are probably incorrect. They should be something like `<input name="course_details[0][d_Total_Score]" ...>` for the validation structure you provided.

Comment: @d3jn, Please check updates

Comment: Based on what `dd($request->input('course_details'))` showed there might be other input with the `name="course_details[d_Total_Score]"` somewhere after your original inputs and it's overriding the value that is sent with the request.

Comment: No this is unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you are looking for like this:

```
course_details.*.d_Total_Score' => 'required'
```

I recently wrote something similar and I did it like this:

```
'contacts.*.name' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
'contacts.*.email' => 'nullable|email|max:255',
'contacts.*.phone' => 'nullable|phone:US|max:255',
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('contacts') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="contacts" name="contacts[0][name]" type="text" value="">
<input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('contacts') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="contacts" name="contacts[0][email]" type="text" value="">
<input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('contacts') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="contacts" name="contacts[0][phone]" type="text" value="">

<input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('contacts') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="contacts" name="contacts[1][name]" type="text" value="">
<input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('contacts') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="contacts" name="contacts[1][email]" type="text" value="">
<input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('contacts') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="contacts" name="contacts[2][name]" type="text" value="">
```

... so on

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean it's passing the validation or are you seeing errors? @DushyantJoshi

Comment: it is passing the validation. Means is is not being called.